# jQuery element click after AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, html-lists, jquery-ui-tabs

My project has a page using jQuery UI Tabs. Each tab calls a file using AJAX, each presenting a list. Each `<li>` element of those lists has a child element like `<input type = "checkbox" />`.

What I need is for the `checkbox` element to be checked or unchecked (depending on its previous state) when I click anywhere on the `<li>`.

I have tried using a function like this `<li onclick = "javascript: CheckboxClick();">` and it worked fine, until the user was trying to click on the actual checkbox. Then, the function was running simultaneously with the checkbox's action causing them to cancel each other.

I've tried using a similar version of the function on `$(document).ready()` in order to exclude the the checkbox child from firing this function, but the lists are created with AJAX and there were not part of the initial DOM. The function did not work. I tried using `click` instead of `on()`, since according to [w3schools on() method explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) it states *"the on() method will work for both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script)."* and I had no success.

The latter try was like this:

```
$("li.single-line.restore-manager").on("click", function () {
    //code

}).children('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (e) {

    return false;
});
```

and actually nothing happens.

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Comment: Doesn't `solve` your problem, but when you run your custom function onclick just check or uncheck it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).on("click", "li.single-line.restore-manager", function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT") {
        var myChks = $(this).children(":checkbox");
        $.each(myChks, function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked") === true) {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            } else {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/jbSNq/1)

Comment: Ah, I see, the kicker is this part: **until the user was trying to click on the actual checkbox. Then, the function was running simultaneously with the checkbox's action causing them to cancel each other.**

Comment: I'm fiddling with it now. :)

Comment: This one does work indeed! Thank you very much for your help buddy! :)

Comment: You might want to check it in a few different browsers (cough, IE, cough). I'm not sure how well IE handles the `event.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code to handle checkbox click:

```
$(document).on("click", 'li.single-line.restore-manager', function(e){ // Use document or parent of li which exists before `AJAX` call
    if (e.target.nodeName != 'INPUT') {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: By mistake I have double quoted the `li` selector `'"li.single-line.restore-manager"'`, correct code is `'li.single-line.restore-manager'`, answer updated